# highchart display goal on mouse hover

Tags: vb.net, highcharts

Below is my code to display highcharts, now in the chart goal is showed on mouse over. i want to display it as thin line:

```
options.series[1] = new Object();
options.series[1].name = "Goal Points";
options.series[1].data = Goallimit;
options.series[1].type = 'arearange';
options.series[1].lineWidth = 0;
options.series[1].linkedTo = ':previous';
options.series[1].color = '#A6E685';
options.series[1].fillOpacity = 0.3;
options.series[1].zIndex = 0;!
```

[Here is Highchart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z86x9.png)

Comment: could you post the rest of the code you are using to generate the chart? Cheers!

Comment: If you have just one point, then where would like to render line?